# Como substituir uma palavra em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como substituir a palavra "Minutes" por "Minutos" que está dentro da div.info-box?

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <span class="date-info">13 de julho de 2021</span>
  <span class="separator-symbol">•</span>
  3 Minutes
</div>
```

Tentei usar essa sintaxe para identificar a palavra a ser substituída e realizar sua substituição, mas não deu certo:

```js
document.querySelector('.info-box').replace('Minutes' , 'Minutos');
```

Também tentei usar .innerText mas ele substitui tudo que está dentro da div.info-box, inclusive os spans.

Comment: Para analisar: qual é o tipo de retorno da função `querySelector`? Esse tipo permite um `replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Você pode utilizar o replace juntamente com o** `Element.innerText`

Dessa forma:

```js
var text = document.querySelector(".info-box")

text = text.innerText.replace("Minutes", "Minutos")

document.querySelector('.info-box').innerText = text
```

```html
<div class="info-box">
  <span class="date-info">13 de julho de 2021</span>
  <span class="separator-symbol">•</span>
  3 Minutes
</div>
```